# Systemd roslaunch

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, startup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've recently migrated my ROS project to Ubuntu 16.04LTS and ROS kinetic since I was having stability issues with Ubuntu 14.04LTS. Unfortunately this means I can't use robot upstart anymore to run my roslaunch file at startup (afaik).

I've made an attempt at using systemd (based on [this guide](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-automatically-execute-shell-script-at-startup-boot-on-systemd-linux)) to run a bash script which runs roslaunch at startup but I'm stuck trying to get everything to work.

my systemd file: (chmod 664)

> [Unit]
>
> Description=start runslam
>
> After=mysql.service
>
> [Service]
>
> ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/runslam.sh
>
> KillMode=process
>
> [Install]
>
> WantedBy=default.target

my bash script: (chmod +x)

> #!/bin/bash
>
> roslaunch runslam slam.launch

Just running the bash script from the terminal starts up roscore and my project runs fine but when running:

> $ sudo systemctl start runslam.service
> >
> > $ systemctl status runslam.service

I get the following output:

> ● runslam.service - start runslam
> Loaded: loaded
> (/etc/systemd/system/runslam.service;
> enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
> Active: failed (Result: exit-code)
> since Thu 2016-10-06 11:36:29 AEST; 7s
> ago   Process: 3746
> ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/runslam.sh
> (code=exited, status=127)  Main PID:
> 3746 (code=exited, status=127)
>
> Oct 06 11:36:29 ausdroid-sbc-flt1 systemd[1]: Started start runslam.

> Oct 06 11:36:29 ausdroid-sbc-flt1 runslam.sh[3746]: /usr/local/bin/runslam.sh: line 3: roslaunch: command not found

> Oct 06 11:36:29 ausdroid-sbc-flt1 systemd[1]: runslam.service: Main process exited,> code=exited, status=127/n/a

> Oct 06 11:36:29 ausdroid-sbc-flt1 systemd[1]:  runslam.service: Unit entered failed  state.

> Oct 06 11:36:29 ausdroid-sbc-flt1 systemd[1]: runslam.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

I think "roslaunch: command not found" means that the ROS environment needs to be somehow specified in the systemd file does anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245089/systemd-roslaunch/) by [Andre_Preller_3000](https://answers.ros.org/users/26157/andre_preller_3000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2016-10-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2020-03-19**:
Note it may be advisable to use [`KillSignal=2`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html) as `roslaunch` seems to respond to `SIGINT` instead of the default `SIGTERM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have not used `systemd` myself for this task, but I've used the following method in a fairly similar situation to wrap `roslaunch`.

Change `/usr/local/bin/runslam.sh` to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
bash -c "source /path/to/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash && roslaunch runslam slam.launch"
```

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2016-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andre_Preller_3000](https://answers.ros.org/users/26157/andre_preller_3000/) on 2016-10-06**:
Brilliant! Thankyou Mani that did it :)

And just for the sake of completeness, since posting I made the following changes to the systemd file:

- "After=network.target"

*got rid of the KillMode line

*Added "Restart=on-abort" under [Unit]

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2016-10-06**:
You are welcome. I am glad it worked. One thing you can do is to post your full solution online (i.e. as a Github gist) and provide a link in your question for future reference.

**Comment by [calvertdw](https://answers.ros.org/users/29941/calvertdw/) on 2017-04-05**:
You sir are a boss. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

FYI:  `(code=exited, status=127)` means that a command is not recognized.
This is because ROS hasn't been sourced when the service is starting up.
As @Mani mentioned: just add the `source /path/to/ros/setup.bash` to you script file so it recognizes the ros commands you use.

---

Originally posted by [Floris](https://answers.ros.org/users/41807/floris/) with karma: 11 on 2019-07-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1